# How would I plot this as a line graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have this data below. I was wondering how I would plot it. This is a dataframe and the first column is the index and the second column holds a timestamp(left number) and then the price. This is only showing the first 5 rows but the dataframe is actually (366, 1). I am not sure how to split the data up so I can make a line chart out of it.

```
             prices
0   [1577836800000, 1.011314677267319]
1   [1577923200000, 1.048537268947032]
2   [1578009600000, 0.9541815075748614]
3   [1578096000000, 0.9551243387141036]
4   [1578182400000, 0.9450787078323388]
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit further? Which column do you want to plot against what data? Are you trying to plot the price against the index, or (somehow) the timestamp?

Comment: Sorry If I was unclear, I am trying to plot the timestamp against the price. But because the data is in one column, I don't know how to separate it into 2 columns and then plot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the column `prices` to a list by [`tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) and store the result in another `DataFrame`. The result can be plotted with the [`plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method of `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

# df = your dataframe
pd.DataFrame(df["prices"].tolist(), columns=["timestamp", "price"]).plot(x="timestamp")
```

Result:

[image]